# Disposing of custom objects

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, idisposable

Is it necessary to dispose of custom objects, even if they only contain managed objects? For example, I have a custom class that contains some List objects, as well as some string and xmldocument types. Should I create my own Dispose method (while NOT inheriting from IDisposable) and just clear those out to make sure they are empty? If I should, should I also inherit from IDisposable?

Comment: "Necessary" is a strong word.  If they are big and unwieldy, or can take up significant, limited resources, it's a good idea to implement IDisposable to aid in freeing those resources.

Comment: The FAQ answer goes in great detail on overall usage of IDisposabe and worth reading [Proper use of the IDisposable interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface).

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs - "big" is not relevant here, it's not about memory. Only about (managed) resources.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, this is true (except it's about *un*managed resources); I stand corrected.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs - unmanaged should be wrapped in SafeHandle and then it's managed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only when one or more of those managed objects inherits from IDisposable.

If you have IDisposable objects (aka managed resources) then implement IDisposable but do *not* add a destructor/finalizer.

Comment: And, if so, also implement IDisposable on the custom class.

Comment: @HenkHolterman the destructor/finalizer, is that the ~[MyCustomClassName] method?

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb you should implement `IDisposable` if any of the managed object instances you reference implement `IDisposable`. You can then dispose those in your `Dispose` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You see, setting the references to `null` at the end of your object's lifetime won't change anything for the garbage collector. If the only remaining references to the contained objects are from your custom object, then the garbage collector treats them as eligible for garbage collection anyway (because it looks only for references from living objects). If there are references from elsewhere, the contained objects won't be collected, no matter if you clean up your references.

Another story is, of course, when some of your contained objects requires explicit disposal, that is, implements `IDisposable`, or requires to be closed at the end of lifetime (although the correct way would be anyway to implement `IDisposable`), etc. This way you perhaps need to implement `IDisposable` yourself, and dispose of the contained objects in your `Dispose`.

Of course, you need to implement `IDisposable` in a special way when you refer to *unmanaged* objects, but this is [another story](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx).